# Should we have a return type added to function binded to ng-Blur or ng-foucs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a doubt related to ng-blur and ng-focus. we have controller binded to ng-focus and ng-blur like below:
on view:

```
<input ng-focus="vm.onFocus" />
```

on controller:

```
vm.onFocus = function ($event) {
    return focus({event: $event});
};

function focus(event) {
    // do something actual implementation contains some condition
    return true;
}
```

Now in above case return is added, 
Any one have any idea whether these returns do really angular resolves?

Comment: why would you need that? ngFocus on this demo works without any return http://jsfiddle.net/deathhell/UTn5y/2/

Comment: its not me acutally the previous developer kept it, and i was cleaning it , so thought have an opinion on it.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Angular will not invoke `focus` function like this. It will properly evaluate `vm.onFocus` expression, and this expression will resolve to a function, no problem here. However, this function is not being *called* (missing `()`).

You could simply make `onFocus` reference `focus` function:

```
vm.onFocus = focus;
```

and make sure you call it:

```
<input ng-focus="vm.onFocus()" />
```

<sub>Although, it is still possible to invoke it even when `ng-focus="vm.onFocus"` is used, but I would not recommend it.</sub>